# Why do I get 2 > 38 == YES?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, comparison

I have a simple `if` statement in my code comparing two variables:

Both currentScore and lpGcScore are `NSNumber`:

```
_lpGcScore = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:board.localPlayerScore.value];
```

And this is how I define currentScore:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // get the score from "db"
NSNumber *currentScore = [defaults valueForKey:@"currentScore"];
```

The if statement:

```
if ((int)currentScore > (int)_lpGcScore) {
        NSLog(@"currentScore: %@ > _lpGcScore: %@", currentScore, _lpGcScore);
}
```

The log and behavious of the application confirm:

`2014-06-15 14:09:53.668 LaserShipDestroyer[4461:60b] currentScore: 2 > _lpGcScore: 38`

I imagine this is truly not a fault in the system/language, maybe I'm doing something weird with the types of numbers I'm comparing in variables?

Comment: You're doing something wrong in one of those lines, because you can't print primitives with `%@`, and you can't cast objects to `int` and compare them as numbers. What are the actual types of `currentScore` and `_lpGcScore`?

Comment: What data type is `currentScore` and `_lpGcScore`?

Comment: I'm still wearing my Ruby coloured glasses...

Comment: There seems to be two votes for off-topic, how is this question off topic or not related to programming?

Comment: The specific "off-topic" reason is "questions seeking debugging help must include code that reproduces the problem". Your question is lacking the information -- the types of your variables -- necessary for anyone else to reproduce your results.

Comment: If you're wondering why that's under "off-topic", well, [a lot of other people do too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because you are casting Objects to Int (`(int)currentScore`), comparing memory adresses and not values?

A cast will never transform an object (`NSNumber *`) to a value type (`int`). Use something like that instead:

```
if ([currentScore intValue] > [_lpGcScore intValue]) ...
```